# Azure Datalake on-premise or hybrid stack

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, azure-stack

We are trying to evaluate a good fit for our solution. We want to process big-data, for that we want build the solution around Hadoop stack. We wanted to know how azure can help in these situations. The solution we are building is a SAAS. But some of our clients have confidential data which they want to hold only in their premise.

1. So can we run azure data lake on premise for those clients?
2. Can we have a hybrid model where storage used will be on premise but the processing done will be on cloud.

The reason we are asking this is to answer the question of scalability and reliability.

I know this is vague but if you need more clarification please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake (gen2) Hierarchical Filesystem support in Azure Stack would enable you to use it natively for your storage requirements. Unfortunately currently Azure Stack does not support Azure Data Lake.

You can find the list of available services here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/overview/azure-stack/keyfeatures/. Some of the big data ecosystem Azure tools are in development but not yet generally available.

There is a feature request to add this support. You can vote this up to help Microsoft prioritize this. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/344565-azure-stack/suggestions/38222872-support-adls-gen2-on-azure-stack